# pd.to_csv results in unexpected row full empty cells (but keeping index name on the same row)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

Below is a snipshot of the pandas DataFrame I want to write to csv:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4NOH.png]

If I do this with the following command line, it results in an unwanted layout:

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\df.csv')
```

The resulted csv looks like:

[image]

The third line appears to be an empty row, but with the index_names in front.

The desired output would be without this empty row:

[image]

Anybody knows what happens here and how I can prevent it from happening?

Anything would help!

(Maybe this has something to do with the MultiIndex header?)